# java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date from ("d MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss zzz")

Tags: java, simpledateformat, parseexception

I get ParseException in second line of the folowing code:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss zzz");
Date response = formatter.parse(dateStr);
```

Exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1 Dec 2014 08:32:59 GMT" (at offset 2)
```

How to solve this?

Comment: It depends on your locale. With `en_US` it works: [DEMO](http://ideone.com/ry5Po5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Locale.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss zzz",
                                                                      Locale.US);
Date response = formatter.parse("1 Dec 2014 08:32:59 GMT");
System.out.println(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why I receive
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "11 Jan 2015 15:56:00" (at offset 0)
for 11 Jan 2015 15:56:00 +0100?!

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = null;
                Date pubDate = null;
                try {
                    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                            "EEE dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
                    pubDate = dateFormat.parse(this.pubDate);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy");
                // convert to format dd/mm/yyyy
                this.pubDate = dateFormat.format(pubDate);
```

Thank you so much!